# Find object based on array element, return only matching array element?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Person object in mongoose, and that person object has multiple things (each thing has a unique ID).

```
person1 = {
  things[{id: 1, name: 'one'},{id:2, name: 'two'}]
}
person2 = {
  things[{id: 3, name: 'three'},{id:4, name: 'four'}]
}
```

then query:

```
Person.findOne({'things.id': 2},{'things.$': 1}, function(err, person) { ...
```

This works great but I am searching through all Person objects (which there could be a lot of).  In this case I know the id of the Person I need and some unique id of a 'thing'.  Its probably a lot faster to get the Person by id:

```
Person.findById(personId, function(err, person) { ...
```

Then loop over all the things to find the right one:

```
var thing
person.things.forEach(function(t) {
  if (t.id == thingId) {
    thing = t;
  }
});
```

What I am wondering is if there is a better way.  I.E. can I query the Person collection by id to get just one Person then filter out just the thing I am looking for (without the ugly loop)?

Comment: What does `things.$` mean? What does the `$` refer to/do?

Comment: The `$` is a positional operator. You can find more details about it in the [Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can include both id terms in a single query and the single element projection will still work:

```
Person.findOne({_id: personId, 'things.id': 2}, {'things.$': 1}, 
    function(err, person) { ...
```

Comment: So that will query on Person first (which should be fast), then on a specific thing for that person?  That is awesome, thanks!

Comment: So does this mean that the person object will be returned with only one element in the things array, that being the thing we are looking for in the query?

Comment: Nice. I am looking now for a way to do this but with findOneAndUpdate, because I need to update only a specific element of a document array. Do you have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678327/how-to-update-particular-array-element-in-mongodb