# Mongoose, find item in a documents array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I have queried a specific document by id from mongoose. That document has an array of items. This list will always be very small (less than 10 items).  I was wondering if there was a way to get a specific item from the array.

Example document:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'some name,
    items: [{
        id: 23,
        name: 'item name 23'
    },{
        id: 24,
        name: 'item name 24'
    }]
}
```

From the mongoose docs I can get the items array:

```
doc.get('items')
```

From there I can iterate over the array and find what I want, which is no big deal. Just don't want to reinvent the wheel if this is provided in the framework.

Comment: If you know the position you can use the "dot notation" (e.g. 'items.0') http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#arrays

Comment: I don't want to find by position, I want to find by id.  I.E. doc.get('items').find(23);  Of course that does not exist just an example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think the solution is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213089/mongodb-mongoose-find-object-based-on-array-element-return-only-matching-array).

Answer (score 14):

I think it will work.

```
Document.findById({docId, 'items.id': 'yourId'}, {'items.$': 1}, function(err, item){

}
```

Comment: If it worked I think you could check it as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: is it possible to only get the requied fields?

Comment: @AryehArmon I think you can include necessary fields just like you would any other query: ```{ <fieldname>: 1 }``` to include fieldname, and exclude the rest, and 0 to exclude a fieldname.

Comment: Although it worked, it would be great to get an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 2):

There is an id method for doing exactly that.

```
doc.items.id(23)
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

The solutions using find or findOne will work but involve more code and are more difficult to understand.